# Mesos master keeps starting automatically

Tags: docker, mesos, mesosphere

I have mesos installed in some docker containers and when ever I bring the container up, the `mesos-master` process starts by default on all these containers. Even on those that I have `mesos-agents` running on. 
I have no idea why this is happening and this is rather annoying.

I am installing mesos the following way

```
RUN rpm -i http://repos.mesosphere.io/el/7/noarch/RPMS/mesosphere-el-repo-7-1.noarch.rpm && \
yum -y install mesos-0.28.2
```

Any ideas on why this is happening? Is this the expected behavior? 
Please let me know what I can do to stop this.

Comment: This happens even if I kill the process. It just keeps starting on its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is expected behavior**

You need to explicit disable Mesos Master (and ZooKeeper if you installed it). Depending on your system version it can be done as follow:

- On RedHat 6 / CentOS 6:

  ```
  sudo stop mesos-master
  sudo sh -c "echo manual > /etc/init/mesos-master.override"
  ```
- On RedHat 7 / CentOS 7:

  ```
  sudo systemctl stop mesos-master.service
  sudo systemctl disable mesos-master.service
  ```

For more take a look at [slave-setup tutorial](https://open.mesosphere.com/getting-started/install/#slave-setup).

Comment: Why is this an expected behavior? Shouldn't it start only when we want it to?

Comment: I think it's a good practice to make rpm package that has default configs and give you running service right after installation and configure upstart for it. I can't find any source if this is recommended practice but at least is followed by some services.

Comment: According to [Fedora guideline](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL:SysVInitScript#Initscripts_on_the_filesystem) starting service after installation is not recommended but seeing init scrip is OK